# Access an element within a file from within a double for loop?

Tags: c++

I have a file with a grid of numbers that I'm trying to iterate through. I know the dimensions of the grid, but I can't seem to find a way to access the value at each location. Here's an outline of what I've got so far in partial pseudocode:

```
std::ifstream file(filename);

for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    string line = file[y];  // wrong
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int value = line[x]  // wrong
    }
}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look more like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    string line;
    getline(file,line);

    std::istringstream line_stream(line);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int value;
        line_stream >> value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access a stream like this, it is serial in nature.Using streams pseudo code could look like this (did not try to compile, however this is the idea)

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {

  std::ifstream ifs ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);

#define LINE_SIZE 10    
  char c = ifs.get();

  for (int i=0;ifs.good();i++) {
      // this element is  at row :(i/LINE_SIZE)  col: i%LINE_SIZE
      int row=(int)(i/LINE_SIZE);
      int col=(i%LINE_SIZE);
    myFunction(row,col,c);
    c = ifs.get();
  }

  ifs.close();

  return 0;
}
```